# Use CloseableHttpClient instead of ClientBuilder

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I have an javax.ws.rs.client ClientBuilder to create httpClient, which takes in some query params and executes it.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(LOCAL_BASE).path(APP_INFO_URI).queryParam("some_param", "true");
response = target.request().header("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
```

I need to use **CloseableHttpClient** httpClient instead. I've been able to create the client, but not sure how to move forward from here.

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(9000)
                .setConnectTimeout(2000)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(1400)
                .build();

PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
cm.setMaxTotal(2); 
cm.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(2); 

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
        .setConnectionManager(cm)
        .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
```

Can someone please help me using the CloseableHttpClient httpClient, how to get the response the way it is done for ClientBuilder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to implement a response handler by implementing the `ResponseHandler` type(or one its adapters/wrappers), and then call the `execute()` method of concreted/built `CloseableHttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to initiate the httpClient, get status and payload.

```
private void invokeHttpClient() throws URISyntaxException {
    // Build the server URI together with the parameters you wish to pass
    uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(LOCAL_BASE+APP_INFO_URI);

    // Create a socketfactory in order to use an http connection manager
    PlainConnectionSocketFactory plainSocketFactory = PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory();
    Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> connSocketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory>create()
            .register("http", plainSocketFactory)
            .build();

    connManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(connSocketFactoryRegistry);
    connManager.setMaxTotal(2); 
    connManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(2); 

    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setSocketTimeout(5000)
            .setConnectTimeout(1000)
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(1000)
            .build();

    httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(connManager)
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();

    List<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair(SomeParam, "Value"));
    uriBuilder.addParameters(postParameters);
    HttpGet postRequest = new HttpGet(uriBuilder.build());
    postRequest.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    String payload = EntityUtils.toString((HttpEntity)response.getEntity());
}
```

Reference - Stackoverflow existing posts.